# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24

Tags: java, crash, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a big problem with my Export function after I input my 2 Files `(Mesh.txt, TH.TXT)`. I really tried to fix this problem, but I am not the best java coder and don't have much experience.

My Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
at eu.keksfabrik.hydrustranslator.HydrusMeshReadout.writeRes2dModFormat(HydrusMeshReadout.java:612)
at eu.keksfabrik.hydrustranslator.HydrusMeshReadout.startWriting(HydrusMeshReadout.java:406)
at eu.keksfabrik.hydrustranslator.LoadFilesGUI.actionPerformed(LoadFilesGUI.java:304)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Links for the Programm Packed:
My Programm full source Code:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zttz9123acaha3x/HydrusTranslator.zip
```

Input Files:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qt2rwc3jdm28vx8/Input%20Files.zip
```

Here my Code of my five files, i zip this too because is so much.

Main GUI:

```
package eu.keksfabrik.hydrustranslator;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import java.awt.Component;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130513;
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainGUI frame = new MainGUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainGUI() {
    try {               
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    setTitle("HYDRUS Filetranslator          \u00a92013 Jan Mahle");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 730, 700);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][]", "[grow][grow]"));

    //JScrollBar wird erzeugt
      // JScrollBar vsb = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL,  1,10,1,100);
     //...und dem JPanel hinzugefügt
      // contentPane.add("East",vsb);

    LoadFilesGUI loadFilesGUI = new LoadFilesGUI(this); 
    loadFilesGUI.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
    contentPane.add(loadFilesGUI, "cell 0 0,growy");
    setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]               {contentPane, loadFilesGUI}));
}
}
```

LoadFilesGUI.java:

```
package eu.keksfabrik.hydrustranslator;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;

public class LoadFilesGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130513;

private MigLayout ml;
private JTextField txtInMESH;
private JTextField txtInTH;
private JTextField txtOut;
private JButton btnMESH;
private JButton btnTH;
private JButton btnOut;
private JButton btnAnalyze;
private JLabel lblMeshtxt;
private JLabel lblThtxt;
private JLabel lblOutput;
private JFileChooser fcMESH;
private JFileChooser fcTH;
private JFileChooser fcCheckOut;
private JFileChooser fcOut;
private File defaultDirectory = null;
private HydrusMeshReadout hmr = null;
private TableGUI tableGUI;
private LoadingDialog loadingDialog;
private JButton addElectrods;
private JTextField nrelectrods;
private JCheckBox chckbxElectrods;
private JTextField tfelecs;

// private JScrollBar scrolli;
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public LoadFilesGUI(JFrame parent) {
    ml = new MigLayout("", "[59.00,left][grow][]", "[][][][][][grow][]");
    setLayout(ml);

    loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(parent);
    loadingDialog.setTitle("Working...");

    lblMeshtxt = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel(
            "*_MESH.TXT");
    add(lblMeshtxt, "cell 0 0,alignx center");

    txtInMESH = new JTextField();
    add(txtInMESH, "cell 1 0,growx");
    txtInMESH.setColumns(10);
    txtInMESH.setEditable(false);

    btnMESH = new JButton("Browse");
    add(btnMESH, "cell 2 0,grow");
    btnMESH.addActionListener(this);

    fcMESH = new JFileChooser();
    fcMESH.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    fcMESH.setDialogTitle("Open *_MESH.TXT ...");
    fcMESH.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("ASCII Files", "TXT"));
    fcMESH.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fcMESH.setDragEnabled(true);
    fcMESH.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fcMESH.addActionListener(this);

    lblThtxt = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("TH.TXT");
    add(lblThtxt, "cell 0 1,alignx center");

    txtInTH = new JTextField();
    add(txtInTH, "cell 1 1,growx");
    txtInTH.setColumns(10);
    txtInTH.setEditable(false);

    btnTH = new JButton("Browse");
    add(btnTH, "cell 2 1,grow");
    btnTH.addActionListener(this);

    fcTH = new JFileChooser();
    fcTH.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    fcTH.setDialogTitle("Open TH.TXT ...");
    fcTH.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("ASCII Files", "TXT"));
    fcTH.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fcTH.setDragEnabled(true);
    fcTH.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fcTH.addActionListener(this);

    fcCheckOut = new JFileChooser();
    fcCheckOut.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    fcCheckOut.setDialogTitle("Open Check.out ...");
    fcCheckOut
            .setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Out Files", "OUT"));
    fcCheckOut.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fcCheckOut.setDragEnabled(true);
    fcCheckOut.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fcCheckOut.addActionListener(this);

    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    add(separator, "cell 0 2 3 1,growx");

    lblOutput = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Output");
    add(lblOutput, "cell 0 3,alignx center");

    txtOut = new JTextField();
    add(txtOut, "cell 1 3,growx");
    txtOut.setColumns(10);
    txtOut.setEditable(false);

    btnOut = new JButton("Browse");
    add(btnOut, "cell 2 3,growx");
    btnOut.addActionListener(this);

    fcOut = new JFileChooser();
    fcOut.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    fcOut.setDialogTitle("Save to...");
    fcOut.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("ASCII Files", "xyz"));
    fcOut.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fcOut.setDragEnabled(true);
    fcOut.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fcOut.addActionListener(this);

    chckbxElectrods = new JCheckBox("Edit Electrods ?");
    chckbxElectrods.setSelected(false);
    chckbxElectrods.setEnabled(true);
    add(chckbxElectrods, "cell 1 4,alignx leading");

    nrelectrods = new JTextField();
    add(nrelectrods, "cell 1 4,growx");
    nrelectrods.setColumns(1);
    nrelectrods.setEditable(true);
    nrelectrods.addActionListener(this);

    addElectrods = new JButton("Set Electrods");
    addElectrods.setEnabled(false);
    add(addElectrods, "cell 1 4,right");
    addElectrods.addActionListener(this);

    tfelecs = new JTextField("");
    tfelecs.setEnabled(false);
    add(tfelecs, "cell 1 4,right");
    tfelecs.addActionListener(this);

    btnAnalyze = new JButton("Analyze");
    btnAnalyze.setEnabled(false);
    add(btnAnalyze, "cell 2 4,growx");
    btnAnalyze.addActionListener(this);

    tableGUI = new TableGUI(this, null);
    // JScrollBar wird erzeugt
    JScrollBar vsb = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL, 1, 10, 1, 100);
    // ...und dem JPanel hinzugefügt
    tableGUI.add("East", vsb);
    tableGUI.setVisible(false);
    add(tableGUI, "cell 0 6 3 1,grow");

}

// public checkelectrods = chckbxElectrods.isEnabled() {

// }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() + "\t" + e.getActionCommand() + "\t"
            + e.getSource().getClass().toString().substring(6));
    if (e.getSource().equals(btnMESH)) {
        if (defaultDirectory != null)
            fcMESH.setCurrentDirectory(defaultDirectory);
        fcMESH.showOpenDialog(btnMESH);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(fcMESH)) {
        defaultDirectory = fcMESH.getCurrentDirectory();
        if (fcMESH.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            txtInMESH.setText(fcMESH.getSelectedFile().toString());
            if (hmr != null)
                hmr = null;
        } else
            txtInMESH.setText("");
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(btnTH)) {
        if (defaultDirectory != null)
            fcTH.setCurrentDirectory(defaultDirectory);
        fcTH.showOpenDialog(btnTH);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(fcTH)) {
        defaultDirectory = fcTH.getCurrentDirectory();
        if (fcTH.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            txtInTH.setText(fcTH.getSelectedFile().toString());
            if (hmr != null)
                hmr = null;
        } else
            txtInTH.setText("");
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(btnOut)) {
        if (defaultDirectory != null)
            fcOut.setCurrentDirectory(defaultDirectory);
        fcOut.showOpenDialog(btnOut);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(fcOut)) {
        defaultDirectory = fcOut.getCurrentDirectory();
        if (fcOut.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            txtOut.setText(fcOut.getSelectedFile().toString());
            if (hmr != null)
                hmr = null;
        } else
            txtOut.setText("");
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(nrelectrods)) {
        chckbxElectrods.setEnabled(false);
        nrelectrods.setText("75");
        nrelectrods.getText();
    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(btnAnalyze)) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        loadingDialog.setMessage("ANALYZING");
                        loadingDialog.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();
        hmr = new HydrusMeshReadout(fcMESH.getSelectedFile(),
                fcTH.getSelectedFile(), fcCheckOut.getSelectedFile(),
                fcOut.getSelectedFile());
        if (tableGUI != null && this.isAncestorOf(tableGUI)) {
            remove(tableGUI);
            repaint();
        }
        tableGUI = new TableGUI(this, hmr.getMaterials());
        add(tableGUI, "cell 0 7 3 1,grow");
        tableGUI.setVisible(true);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        // System.out.println("tableGUI = new TableGUI(this, hmr.getMaterials());\t"
        // + hmr.getMaterials().toString());
        btnAnalyze.setEnabled(false);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        loadingDialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("startEvaluating")) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        loadingDialog.setMessage("WRITING FILES");
                        loadingDialog.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();
        /*
         * new Thread() {
         * 
         * @Override public void run() { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new
         * Runnable() { public void run() {
         */
        hmr.setModel(tableGUI.getRhoadesEquations());
        boolean[] fo = tableGUI.getFileOptions();
        hmr.setTime(tableGUI.getSelectedTime());
        hmr.startWriting(fo[0], fo[1], fo[2], fo[3], fo[4], fo[5],
                tableGUI.getFileFormat());
        /*
         * } }); }; }.start();
         */
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        loadingDialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();
    }
    if (hmr == null) {
        tableGUI.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (!txtInMESH.getText().equals("") && !txtInTH.getText().equals("")
            && !txtOut.getText().equals("") && hmr == null) {
        btnAnalyze.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btnAnalyze.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Double> getAverageWaterContent() {
    return hmr == null ? new ArrayList<Double>() : hmr
            .getAverageWaterContent();
}

public ArrayList<Double> getTimes() {
    return hmr == null ? new ArrayList<Double>() : hmr.getTimes();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static class LoadingDialog extends JDialog {
    private JLabel imglabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    private JFrame owner;

    public LoadingDialog(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        this.owner = owner;
        setUndecorated(true);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("loading.gif"));
        label.setFont(new Font(label.getFont().toString(), Font.BOLD, label
                .getFont().getSize() * 2));
        panel.add(imglabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(panel);
        setMessage("PROCESSING IMAGES");
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        label.setText(message);
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(label.getText().length()
                * label.getFont().getSize(), label.getHeight() * 2));
        setLocation((int) owner.getX()
                + (owner.getWidth() - getSize().width) / 2,
                (int) owner.getY() + (owner.getHeight() - getSize().height)
                        / 2);
        pack();
        repaint();
        // System.err.println(this.getSize().getWidth() + "x" +
        // this.getSize().getHeight());
    }
}
 }
```

OK I see I cant enter here the whole code, maybe u can help me anyway....
Please check the zip file where my source code is inside.

thanks for helping.

Comment: A tip: nobody is going to download your ZIP, unpack it, and study everything within. That's what you *pay* people to do.

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through your code with a debugger? (which is something you should always do before asking a question on Stack Overflow)